# Is Cassandra just a storage engine?

Tags: cassandra

I've been evaluating Cassandra to replace MySQL in our microservices environment, due to MySQL being the only portion of the infrastructure that is not distributed. Our needs are both write and read intensive as it's a platform for exchanging raw data. A type of "bus" for lack of better description. Our selects are fairly simple and should remain that way, but I'm already struggling to get past some basic filtering due to the extreme limitations of select queries.

For example, if I need to filter data it has to be in the key. At that point I can't change data in the fields because they're part of the key. I can use a SASI index but then I hit a wall if I need to filter by more than one field. The hope was that materialized views would help with this but in another post I was told to avoid them, due to some instability and problematic behavior.

It would seem that Cassandra is good at storage but realistically, not good as a standalone database platform for non-trivial applications beyond very basic filtering (i.e. a single field.) I'm guessing I'll have to accept the use of another front-end like Elastic, Solr, etc. The other option might be to accept the idea of filtering data within application logic, which is do-able, as long as the data sets coming back remain small enough.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Cassandra is far more than just a storage engine.  Its design is a distributed database oriented towards providing high availability and partition tolerance which can limit query capability if you want good and reliable performance.

It has a query engine, CQL, which is quite powerful, but it is limited in a way to guide user to make effective queries.  In order to use it effectively you need to model your tables around your queries.

More often than not, you need to query your data in multiple ways, so users will often denormalize their data into multiple tables.  Materialized views aim to make that user experience better, but it has had its share of bugs and limitations as you indicated.  At this point if you consider using them you should be aware of their limitations, although that is generally good idea for evaluating anything.

If you need advanced querying capabilities or do not have an ahead of time knowledge of what the queries will be, Cassandra may not be a good fit.  You can build these capabilities using products like Spark and Solr on top of Cassandra (such as what DataStax Enterprise does), but it may be difficult to achieve using Cassandra alone.

On the other hand there are many use cases where Cassandra is a great fit, such as messaging, personalization, sensor data, and so on.